# sendKeys.RETURN not working in FirefoxDriver

Tags: java, firefox, sendkeys, enter, selenium-webdriver

if I execute the following code in FireFoxDriver:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElements(By.id("some_id")); // element being a textbox
element.sendKeys("apple"); 
element.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

The `sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)` is not performing its desired function. 
Actually what I am trying to do is Input a text in a dynamic text search box (like one in facebook search) and press enter. The input is working fine but not the enter key.

`sendKeys("apple")` works, even `sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)` works, but not `Keys.RETURN`.

Does anyone have ideas? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure why this happens, but there are a couple alternate ways of doing this that may help:

If elements are in a form, and there is no javascript that runs on submit or something you can use .submit() on any form input element, such as inputs and textareas:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElements(By.id("some_id"));
element.sendKeys("apple");
element.submit()
```

You can send the newline character with your input:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElements(By.id("some_id"));
element.sendKeys("apple\n");
```

Provide send_keys a list:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElements(By.id("some_id"));
element.sendKeys("apple", Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution to the above problem. U just need to add, a delay.
This happens because the Java Class runs too fast, so if u have sent a call, and pressed enter/ tab, before the element arrives, the enter is pressed, that is why this doesn't work. Just add Thread.delay(1000); before your Keys.RETURN command. That will do. 
Worked for me.

Comment: You really shouldn't hardcode sleeps() into your program, you should look into Implicit wait - Documentation [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#implicit-waits)

Comment: You probably want to be a little bit more careful with your terminology.  Keys.RETURN will press the return key and Keys.ENTER will press the enter key.  They are different.

Answer (score 0):

I tried sending \n and fiddled with various commands until I found someone explaining that "keyPress (target) 13" will send the return key.

So first I use type to enter the string I want ...

*

```
*<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=status</td>
    <td>This is my test string</td>
</tr>*
```

*

... and then send the Enter key to the same text input box

*

```
*<tr>
    <td>keyPress</td>
    <td>id=status</td>
    <td>13</td>
</tr>*
```

*